# Setting up a RocketMQ cluster: slave not visible & not replicating

Tags: rocketmq

I'm trying to set up a RocketMQ cluster, with a single name server, 1 master and 2 slaves. But, I'm running into some problems.

The version I'm running is downloaded from [github/rocketmq-all-4.1.0-incubating.zip](https://github.com/apache/incubator-rocketmq/archive/rocketmq-all-4.1.0-incubating.zip).

The brokers are run using `mqbroker -c broker.conf`, where broker.conf
differs for master and slave. For the master I have:

```
listenPort=10911
brokerName=mybroker
brokerClusterName=mybrokercluster
brokerId=0
deleteWhen=04
fileReservedTime=48
brokerRole=SYNC_MASTER
flushDiskType=ASYNC_FLUSH
```

And for slaves:

```
listenPort=10911
brokerName=mybroker
brokerClusterName=mybrokercluster
brokerId=1
deleteWhen=04
fileReservedTime=48
brokerRole=SLAVE
flushDiskType=ASYNC_FLUSH
```

The second slave has `brokerId=2`.
Brokers start up fine, some parts of the logs for a slave:

```
2017-10-02 20:31:35 INFO main - brokerRole=ASYNC_MASTER
2017-10-02 20:31:35 INFO main - flushDiskType=ASYNC_FLUSH
(...)
2017-10-02 20:31:35 INFO main - Replace, key: brokerId, value: 0 -> 1
2017-10-02 20:31:35 INFO main - Replace, key: brokerRole, value:
ASYNC_MASTER -> SLAVE
(...)
2017-10-02 20:31:37 INFO main - Set user specified name server address:
172.22.1.38:9876
2017-10-02 20:31:37 INFO ShutdownHook - Shutdown hook was invoked, 1
2017-10-02 20:31:37 INFO ShutdownHook - shutdown thread
PullRequestHoldService interrupt false
2017-10-02 20:31:37 INFO ShutdownHook - join thread PullRequestHoldService
eclipse time(ms) 0 90000
2017-10-02 20:31:37 WARN ShutdownHook - unregisterBroker Exception,
172.22.1.38:9876
org.apache.rocketmq.remoting.exception.RemotingConnectException: connect to
<172.22.1.38:9876> failed
at
org.apache.rocketmq.remoting.netty.NettyRemotingClient.invokeSync(NettyRemotingClient.java:359)
~[rocketmq-remoting-4.1.0-incubating.jar:4.1.0-incubating]
at
org.apache.rocketmq.broker.out.BrokerOuterAPI.unregisterBroker(BrokerOuterAPI.java:221)
~[rocketmq-broker-4.1.0-incubating.jar:4.1.0-incubating]
at
org.apache.rocketmq.broker.out.BrokerOuterAPI.unregisterBrokerAll(BrokerOuterAPI.java:198)
~[rocketmq-broker-4.1.0-incubating.jar:4.1.0-incubating]
at
org.apache.rocketmq.broker.BrokerController.unregisterBrokerAll(BrokerController.java:623)
[rocketmq-broker-4.1.0-incubating.jar:4.1.0-incubating]
at
org.apache.rocketmq.broker.BrokerController.shutdown(BrokerController.java:589)
[rocketmq-broker-4.1.0-incubating.jar:4.1.0-incubating]
at org.apache.rocketmq.broker.BrokerStartup$1.run(BrokerStartup.java:218)
[rocketmq-broker-4.1.0-incubating.jar:4.1.0-incubating]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_141]
2017-10-02 20:31:37 INFO ShutdownHook - Shutdown hook over, consuming total
time(ms): 25
2017-10-02 20:31:45 INFO BrokerControllerScheduledThread1 - dispatch behind
commit log 0 bytes
2017-10-02 20:31:45 INFO BrokerControllerScheduledThread1 - Slave fall
behind master: 0 bytes
2017-10-02 20:31:45 INFO BrokerControllerScheduledThread1 - register broker
to name server 172.22.1.38:9876 OK
2017-10-02 20:32:15 INFO BrokerControllerScheduledThread1 - register broker
to name server 172.22.1.38:9876 OK
```

As I suspect the broker is trying to connect to the name server, which
isn't running initially, so it retries and eventually succeeds?

However, later when trying clusterList I only see one broker listed, which happens to be a slave (`172.22.1.17`) and has `brokerId=2` in the configuration (although here it's listed as 0):

```
$ ./mqadmin clusterList -n 172.22.1.38:9876
#Cluster Name     #Broker Name            #BID  #Addr
 #Version                #InTPS(LOAD)       #OutTPS(LOAD) #PCWait(ms) #Hour
#SPACE
mybrokercluster     mybroker                  0     172.22.1.17:10911
 V4_1_0_SNAPSHOT          0.00(0,0ms)         0.00(0,0ms)          0
418597.80 -1.0000
```

Moreover, when sending messages to the master, I get `SLAVE_NOT_AVAILABLE`.

Why is that? Are the brokers configured properly? If so, wy does
`clusterList` report them incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

you should change slave port,as you know 10911 has been used by anthoer process(master node),slave should be use different tcp port(eg.10921/10931 and so on)

tips:my cluster deploy on one machine,so i changed tcp port and startup successful,if you master&slave deploy on different machine and startup failed,you should visit rocketmq error log for more information.

notice:one master which have more than one slave,brokerId should be different